# CDAP Trucate a long type column representing an epoch in milliseconds to year/month

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I'm using CDAP and *Cloud Data Fusion 6.6.0* I have a column called `ts` with a `long` representing a timestamp in milliseconds. The type is `long`.

In the next step, I need to group by year and month, so I need to create two new fields `year` and `month` or truncate `ts` to month.

What is the set of Wrangler directives to do it?
The next example is not working because it is a `long` so I suppose that I need to transform `ts` to `ZoneDateTime`, but no idea how to do it:

Tested directives:

```
parse-as-simple-date:ts
set-column year date:YEAR(ts)
set-column month date:MONTH(ts)
```

Error

```
Improper usage of directive 'parse-as-simple-date', usage - 'parse-as-simple-date :column 'format''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the wrangler directives to use:

- `timestamp-to-datetime`
- `parse-timestamp`

The directive that you are currently using needs to have a date format such as `yyyy.MM.dd` it would be something like: `parse-as-simple-date :ts yyyy.MM.dd` but this function parse a `DATE STRING` to a `DATE`.

The wrangler directive [`timestamp-to-datetime`](https://github.com/data-integrations/wrangler/blob/develop/wrangler-docs/directives/timestamp-to-datetime.md) converts a timestamp to a datetime.

```
timestamp-to-datetime :ts
```

Another possible solution is to use [`parse-timestamp`](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/382107891/Parse+Timestamp+directive) this directive parses column values representing unix timestamp as date and then you could format the result to a `DATE` pattern that you like.

```
parse-timestamp :ts milliseconds
format-date :ts 'MM/dd/yyyy'
```